# Замена слова в строке и его производных

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с задачей,которую пытался сам решить,но ввиду малого опыта не понимаю как лучше подойти к ее решению

Допустим есть текст:

'Мы посмотрели, а там - пожар! И не просто пожар, а пожарище! Полыхало так, что наш пожар было видно за горами, и не просто пожар или пожарчик, а пожарище!'

Задание: написать функцию,которая будет заменять строку "пожар" и все его производные на "...".

Пытался решить сам:

```
function mchs(str) {
    const fire = /пожар/
    let newStr = str.split(fire).join('~~');
    
    return newStr;
}
```

Но тут я просто не могу еще разобраться как в регулярное выражение добавить еще элементы для поиска (пока ищу в интернете)

```
function mchs(str) {
    let newStr = str.split(' ').map((item) => item.includes('пожар') ? item = `...` : item).join(' ');

    return newStr;
}
```

Да, этот вариант вроде работает, НО он стирает все знаки препинания с собой (пожар!, становится ... без знака !. Аналогично по всему остальному текту)

Comment: достаточно указать в регулярном выражении, что после основы `пожар` могут идти еще русские буквы: `/пожар([а-яё]+)?/g`

Comment: Еще можно добавить флаги **ui**. `/пожар([а-яё]+)?/gui` i - без учета регистра, u - с поддержкой юникода. Тогда попадут строки `Пожарные`

Comment: а что означает знак ? после скобок?

Comment: О сколько интересного про русский язык вам ещё предсторит узнать. Например во фразе «Я решил пожарить котлеты и случился пожар» нужно ли заменять слово «пожарить»?

Comment: А если вместо «пожар» в задании будет слово «воробей»? «Я увидел воробья. Воробей сидел на дереве» — Как вы будете искать «воробья»?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, вы очень забавный) 
Но все же можно ближе к задаче обратиться или вы просто хотите блеснуть знаниями производных предлогов?

Comment: Ближе к задаче вам уже ответили в первом комментарии

Comment: @Grundy 

Не знаю пока что с чем это связано, но  строка возвращается в таком виде:

Мы посмотрели, а там - ~~~~! И не просто ~~~~, а ~~ище~~! Полыхало так, что наш ~~~~ было видно за горами, и не просто ~~~~ или ~~чик~~, а ~~ище~~!

То есть производные слова изменяются, но не полностью

Comment: @Meres, скорее всего ты используешь не то регулярное выражение. Либо не так :)

Comment: @Grundy

function mchs(str) {
    const fire = /пожар([а-яё]+)?/g
    let newStr = str.split(fire).join('~~');

    return newStr;
}

Должно же вот так это выглядеть?

Comment: @Meres, конечно же это не должно так выглядеть :) тебе нужно произвести замены в строке - для этого лучше использовать метод `.replace`

Comment: @Meres, зачем удалять вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно указать в регулярном выражении, что после основы пожар могут идти еще русские буквы: `/пожар([а-яё]+)?/g`

Для замены лучше воспользоваться методом [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
console.log(
  'Мы посмотрели, а там - пожар! И не просто пожар, а пожарище! Полыхало так, что наш пожар было видно за горами, и не просто пожар или пожарчик, а пожарище!'.replace(/пожар([а-яё]+)?/g, "...")
);
```

Если очень хочется использовать именно [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), стоит помнить особенность, что в выходной массив будут входить разделители указанные в группах.

Для их исключения нужно воспользоваться [Non-capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges), обозначающимися `(?:x)`

```js
console.log(
  'Мы посмотрели, а там - пожар! И не просто пожар, а пожарище! Полыхало так, что наш пожар было видно за горами, и не просто пожар или пожарчик, а пожарище!'.split(/пожар(?:[а-яё]+)?/).join("...")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из ответа @Grundy можно дополнить регулярное выражение не просто заменой на какие-то символы, а заменой тем количеством символов, что и найденная строка.

Таким образом можно точно определить количество букв.

Документация по: [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const text = 'Мы посмотрели, а там - пожар! И не просто пожар, а пожарище! Полыхало так, что наш пожар было видно за горами, и не просто пожар или пожарчик, а пожарище!';

const regexp = /пожар([а-яё]+)?/g;

const replace_word = '[]';

const replacerCallback = (match) => replace_word.repeat(match.length)

console.log(text.replace(regexp, replacerCallback));
```